# Recover deleted file in sublime text 3.0?

Tags: file, recover

I just hit "delete folder" by mistake while I was trying to rename a file in Sublime Text 3.0. It seems that it's gone forever. Is there any desperate way of recovering that file ?

- I was working on winSshFS directly local, no github.
- It is not in my Recycle Bin

Answer (score 0):

For Windows
Locate to where you have deleted the file/folder, press ctrl+z, it will recover the files you have deleted.